# Flask MongoDB How to sort string field with integer values?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a model

```
class Ticket(db.Document):
    created = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    ticket_number = db.StringField(unique=True)
```

I have ticket_number with integer values but stored as a string field.
I want to query the ticket with the highest ticket number.
What I have tried is

```
Ticket.objects.order_by('-ticket_number').first().ticket_number
```

But it returns `9` where it should be `20`.
The issue is the queryset gets sorted by string methods.
Is there any way to sort it numerically?
Or does mongo has some query functions like `Cast` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution that works for me.

Adding `numericOrdering` to the query as collation resolves the issue.
The final query will look like

```
 Ticket.objects.order_by("-ticket_number")
            .collation({"locale": "en_US", "numericOrdering": True})
            .first()
```